# Make admin directory be the default directory laravel

Tags: laravel

How can I make an admin directory be the default directory when website is loaded? I'm using laravel-admin as admin panel and I can access it by console.siteexample.com/admin, but how can I change it to access it only with console.siteexample.com ? Which is the best way to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an index view on the view directory.

and define the home route on the web.php file.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('index'); });
```

Comment: Thank you! I've managed by making view('admin/login')